# CCSprites class cast exception in android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I have one problem in inheriting CCSprites in java, i post some of codes here,

```
public class Block extends CCSprite
  {
static Block temp=null;
     ...
     ...
   static Block newBlock(tetrominoTypes blockType)
      {
        temp = (Block) Block.sprite(filename); // class cast exception here

   }
return temp;
 }
```

......
}

Class cast expection occur on runtime , how can i resolve it.If any one knows means help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`sprite` seems to be a static function of the mother class.

Maybe try :

```
temp = (Block) CCSprite.sprite(filename);
```